# libspotify API: image ID format?

Tags: spotify

Is the image ID returned by **sp_album_cover** and **sp_artist_portrait** zero terminated? or is its length fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an opaque struct: i.e., its contents are undefined.

If you want a sane way of printing or storing an image, convert it to a link then a string: `sp_link_create_from_image()` followed by `sp_link_as_string()`.

Comment: **sp_image_create** takes 20 bytes long image_id parameter. Does that mean the maximum length of image id is 20 bytes?

Comment: No. `sp_subscribers` is another example of where we've put a fake number in for the compiler.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: The contents of an image id pointer are opaque and likely to change between releases. Don't write code that makes assumptions about them, because it'll break.